# AnalysisException: Operation not allowed: `CREATE TABLE LIKE` is not supported for Delta tables;

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

```sql
create table if not exists map_table like position_map_view;
```

While using this it is giving me operation not allowed error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-like.html), you need to use `CREATE TABLE AS`, just use `LIMIT 0` in SELECT:

```sql
create table map_table as select * from position_map_view limit 0;
```

Comment: This does not preserve partitioning information

Comment: you can specify `partitioned by` explicitly. I understand that it's not straightforward, but it's still possible to do things programmatically, for example combining `show create table` with some text manipulation

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an easy way of getting `CREATE TABLE LIKE` to work, but I've got a workaround. On DBR in Databricks you should be able to use [SHALLOW CLONE](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-clone.html) to do something similar:

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE $new_database.$new_table 
SHALLOW CLONE $original_database.$original_table`;
```

You'll need to replace `$template`s manually.
Notes:

1. This has an added side-effect of preserving the table content in case you need it.
2. Ironically, creating empty table is much harder and involves manipulating `show create table` statement with custom code